# How to determine the vqmver in a vQmod xml script?

Tags: vqmod

How can I determine the "correct" version of vqmver for the following **vQmod** xml script?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <modification
                xmlns="https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vqmod/vqmod/master/vqmod.xsd"
                >
        <id>Replace 123 with ABC</id>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <vqmver>2.5.0</vqmver>
        <author>qphoria</author>
        <file name="relative/path/myfile.php">
            <operation>
                <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
                $var = '123';
                ]]></search>
                <add><![CDATA[
                $var = 'ABC';
                ]]></add>
            </operation>
        </file>
    </modification>
```

I have found some information here https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Scripting , but it doesn't explain in more details.

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?!?!